# Bing maps How to get the common square of two location rectangles

Tags: math, geometry, bing-maps

I have 2 rectangles which the first is the current map boundary and the second is the previous map boundary (before movement):

```
 LocationRect currentBounds = map.Bounds; //the first.

 LocationRect previousBounds --> //the second.
```

How can I get the common square of them?
In math terms (I think) it means the intersect between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
Rectangle
{
    left,
    top,
    right,
    bottom
}

Rectangle Intersection(Rectangle A, Rectangle B)
{
    return Rectangle
    {
        left = max(A.left, B.left),
        top = max(A.top, B.top),
        right = min(A.right, B.right),
        bottom = min(A.bottom, B.bottom)
    }
}
```

This assumes that the Y values increase going from top to bottom.  If the opposite is true, simply toggle the `min`/`max` calls for `top` and `bottom`.